# Does fetching from a HashMap to add to an ArrayList store it in the ArrayList by reference?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, hashmap, pass-by-reference

If I have a HashMap map that contains values and I want to add those values into an ArrayList, does create copies of those objects when storing them in the ArrayList?

For example, if I do:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
list.add(map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> key));
```

Would adding to the list result in consuming more memory? I read that hashmap fetches value by reference.

Comment: A reference (only) to the object will be stored in both the Map and ArrayList.

Comment: So does this mean that we are not creating multiple copies as a result when adding to the ArrayList and this leads to memory savings? Wondering if I pass fetch it from the map to build a new object and assign that fetched value as one of its field variable if that would still lead to memory savings for duplicate field variables

Comment: Adding any object to any collection/map in Java will never result in a new/copied object being created. There will be some memory increase since a new pointer to the object has to be stored in the map/array/collection, but it's just the pointer.  Strings are not the best test-case for this, because Strings in Java are immutable. But you could test with a different object type, add to both, change the state of the object, then fetch from both and you'll see they both have the change you made. Something like a java.util.Date would be a good object to test this with.

Comment: You could also use the == operator to compare the two objects you fetch from your two data structures.   The "==" operator returns true only if the two reference point to the same object in memory.